# Is there a way to get user location from Twitter location with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I have a dataset filled with scraped tweets. The Twitter user location is also included, and oftentimes it is an actual location such as a city, but oftentimes users just put random text there. Is there a method in Python to determine which country is the tweet most likely from?

My initial idea was to have an API insert the texts into Google Maps, and return the top result (or a "Missing" value if there are no results). However, I was unable to find any feasible methods for this, so I am stuck.

Comment: Add some tweets samples and the code you're currently using for this requirement